# ACF Medical data compare two medicines

Tags: jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF Plugin to store medical data.
For instance Medicine name, Supplier, dosage, side effect...etc.

What I am trying to achieve is to compare two medicines:
I have two textbox's and the user will input the medicine name in them.

I need to build a jquery front end and a PHP backend page to retrieve each medicine info and display them in adjacent tables.

Is that possible to do with ACF Plugin.

I used this query in phpMyAdmin but it doesn't seem to help:

```
select distinct post_id, post_title,wp_postmeta.meta_value from wp_postmeta left join wp_posts on wp_posts.id=wp_postmeta.post_id where (meta_key='dd_agent' or meta_key='dd_name' or meta_key='dd_commercial_name') and wp_posts.post_type="post" and wp_posts.post_status="publish"
```

Comment: Hello justcoder. Just to clarify: you want the user to search medicines by name, then list all medicines with that name next to each other in a table making it easy for the user to compare attributes?

Comment: @JackTempleman, exactly except that they will search two medicines at a time and compare; for example Panadol and Panadol extra

Comment: Ahh okay I understand. The ACF plugin is used just to help make building Wordpress custom meta fields easier. You have probably already used it to build your medicine custom meta fields? When it comes to using that data in your theme, thats left up to you. You are correct in saying you need to build a JS front end to get the search params and then send to the PHP back end to search the database. You should not need to build custom SQL queries as you have done above though. In fact I would *strongly* advise against this. Use WP_Query to search the database for the title then return the results.

Comment: @JackTempleman Yes, I used it to build the medicine custom meta fields. a PHP code will be appreciated as I don't know how to use WP_Query.

Comment: It would be good for your to have a look into it yourself as its essential for WP development. Might look a bit overwhelming at first but you need to have a basic understanding if your working with WP. Here's a couple of links to help point you in the right direction: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#search-parameters. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/. Good luck! :)

Comment: Even if you have a crack at it and post another question on here with your attempt. People will appreciate the fact you had a stab yourself and you will get more responses :)

Comment: @JackTempleman Thank you for your help. I will look into WP_Query. And I am not going to post same issue in another question!